# How can I make an ImageView NOT show until after my animation has run?

Tags: android, animation

I have an activity that is a blank screen except for one ImageView object that has it's gravity set to center. Then in my res\anim directory, I animate that image, basically moving it from the bottom of the screen to the center (rising up), using . What I'm trying to figure out is how to have the activity load with a blank screen, not showing the ImageView until after the animation finishes with the image centered. What happens right now is the screen shows with the image already in the center, then the animation takes over and moves it from bottom to top. How Can I make the animation happen first, before showing the ImageView?

EDIT...Please see new/related question below:

OK, the .setVisibilty works (thanks for the help), but it's led me to another problem. In my xml layout file for this activity, I only have 2 objects, a TextView at the top of the screen (using LinearLayout) and then an ImageView that is set to:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Image01"
        android:src="@drawable/image_01"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="10px"
        >
    </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This puts the image dead center of the screen. What I want the animation to do is have the image rise from the bottom of the screen to the center. The problem is that even if I have the .setVisibility to INVISIBLE in the onCreate, then set to VISIBLE after I start the animation, it still flashes the image in the dead center of the screen (for about half a second), then immediately drops to the bottom and rises back up to center. This looks sloppy. How can I make the image never show until appears at bottom then rise to the center? I beg for specifics, as I'm just getting feet wet with java and xml.

Final EDIT...

Never mind, this only seems to happen in the emulator.  It works fine on the phone.

Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your image is invisible when the activity starts, by setting the `android:visibility` attribute to `invisible`, or by using `setVisibility()` in `onCreate()`.

Then start the animation and call setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) in one go:

```
image.startAnimation(...);
image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Don't I need to reference the image name or id somewhere or does it know it's the image used in the animation?

Comment: Yes, of course, you need to retrieve the image view, with something like image = (ImageView) findViewById(...), if that's what you mean. And technically, the image isn't "used" in the animation, it is the animation which is applied to the image view.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look at `theImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

And you can get information on what your animation is doing (if it's done) with an `AnimationListener`.

The AnimationListener will have something like this:

```
AnimationListener a_to_b = new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // Do something 
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // Do something         
            }
        };
```

and you set it by:

```
Animation ani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.ani);

ani.setAnimationListener(a_to_b);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but I'm at the early learning stages of java.  Do I put either my image name or the @id of the image somewhere in the call theImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)?

Comment: As olivierg said, you need to retrieve the image view like this:
`ImageView image;`
`image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageNameInXml);`

Comment: OK, so let's say the @id for this image is "Image01".  I'd say:

Comment: Sorry, I posted that above comment before I finished it.  OK, so let's say the @id for this image is "Image01". I'd type: ImageView image; image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image01);  Then, where, specifically do I reference image in this call... theImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: The ImageView object name would be "image" because of `ImageView image;`. So you would write `image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`. The "theImageView" was just an example. Sorry if I made it confusing

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Sometimes my brain runs a little slow.  Any thoughts on me edited addition that I added to my original question?

Comment: Seems like you got it to work? Remember to accept an answer if your problem was solved. I believe both answers will work, just different ways to do it.